# Better hash function for user defined type in unordered map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I have the following hash function defined for my case where as a key I have two integers. Here is my code:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int> key_t;
struct KeyHasher
{
  std::size_t operator()(const key_t& k) const
  {
    using std::size_t;
    using std::hash;


    return ((hash<int>()(std::get<0>(k))
             ^ (hash<int>()(std::get<1>(k)) << 1)));
  }
};
```

I want the results to be faster in searching using keys but the execution time seems to be very slow. Please guide me if I can make this hash function for my unorderedmap better than the above one.(I have much more than 2000000 entries)

P.S: I have to make another unordered_map with two unsigned chars as key.Can I define same type of hash function for them as well with types changed to unsigned char?

Comment: Have you done profiling?

Comment: What makes you think that your hash function is better that the implementation's?

Comment: also try to preallocate the hashtable size with function reserve. Make it quite bigger than the number of elements you have.

Comment: @vonbrand I read that for user defined types, I have to make my own hash function. Because when I don't create the hash function , it gives me lots of errors on terminal.